# Measuring max stack usage of a thread in visual studio

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio, stack-overflow

I am trying to figure out how it is possible to measure the max stack usage of a thread on windows platform using visual studio using a code that is written in C ?

I was thinking to use the TID structure , but it gives me only the current stack usage , and not the MAX stack usage.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: While it will most likely not be totally accurate, you can sample the current stack size over the runtime of your thread, and only keep the highest value (as well as get a minimum, mean and average).

Comment: I am talking about a very big software , with a lot of threads

Comment: By the way, *why* do you want to measure the stack usage? What is the problem that's supposed to solve? This question is a classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where you have a solution you want our help with, but don't tell us what the solution is supposed to solve.

Comment: Well, explain what you mean, then.  Do you want the max stack size used of any thread?  The max size allocated to all the stacks together?  Anyway, OS typically don't bother to attempt to determine that 'lowest ESP value over the length of the app run for each thread' because it's of little use and would impact performance to record it.  Why waste time/effort recording such stuff when the next process run might need more recursion or more threads?  The OS does not care about user stack use except for paging in/out and keeping the lid on max use as defined in the executable header.

Answer (score -1):

Windows thread stacks are contiguous and don't shrink once memory is committed to them, so all you need is the top & bottom of stack from the Thread Execution Block, which are present in the second and third words (although in principle this is internal detail subject to change without notice, in practice this has been true since relatively early days of Win32)

So for the current thread something like this:

```
struct _TEB* teb = NtCurrentTeb();
__int64 stkSize = UINT_PTR(teb->Reserved1[1]) - UINT_PTR(teb->Reserved1[2]);
```

And to look across all threads start with NtQueryInformationThread(), e.g. see [Getting the TEB of a 64bit process on WIndows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152735/getting-the-teb-of-a-64bit-process-on-windows)